# Problems while moving picturebox on ellipse

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I want to make a program that simulate planets moving in solar system but some planet is going out of the orbit.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQrw0.jpg)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAVxu.jpg)

Here I try to move the planets around the sun.

`planetDay` is number of days on that planet reported to a day of earth

The planets is not following the orbit and i think here is the problem but I'm not sure, when I modify the location of planet I convert X and Y to int and when I do this I round that numbers

```
private void MovePlanets()
{
        double x;
        double y;

        int k = 0;

        foreach (PictureBox pic in pictureBox1.Controls)
        {
            if (pic.Name == "sun")
            {
                continue;
            }

            x = sun.Location.X + (rectangle[k].Width / 2 * Math.Cos(planetDay[k] + alpha));
            y = sun.Location.Y + (rectangle[k].Height / 2 * Math.Sin(planetDay[k] + alpha));
            pic.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y));
            k++;

            if (k == 8)
            {
                k = 0;
            }
        }

        alpha += 0.1;
}
```

Here I generate the rectangle that I use to draw the ellipses

```
private void Orbit()
{      
        int x1 = 30;

        foreach (PictureBox pic in pictureBox1.Controls)
        {
            if (pic.Name == "sun")
            {
                continue;
            }

            Rectangle r = new Rectangle
               (
                   pic.Location.X + pic.Size.Width / 2,
                   (sun.Location.Y + sun.Size.Width / 2) - x1,
                   ((sun.Location.X + sun.Size.Width / 2) - (pic.Location.X + pic.Size.Width / 2)) * 2,
                   x1 * 2
               );
            rectangle.Add(r);
            x1 += 36;

        }
}
```

And here I draw the ellipses

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.White, 1f);

        foreach (Rectangle rec in rectangle)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(p, rec);
        }
}
```

Can someone help me with that problem ?

Comment: Seems like only the Mercury is incorrect, is it? You could check by debugging its value versus the actual points in the ellipse (orbit)

Comment: mercury and mars a little bit

Comment: My first suspect would be due to rounding off of the integers when you use something like `Height`, `Width`, etc... Try to convert each of them to `double` type first and see if the problem still persists

Comment: i show in a message box the values, this is what i get:

Double:
x= 487,5955608...
y= 291,1310786...

Int
x=488
y=291

Comment: and how can i fix this ?

Comment: You should store the locations as floats (or double) __all the time__! Only convert when setting the Locations but do all calculations in floating point and using Math.Round! So create a data structure to hold the data. A Dictionary(string, PointF) is cheap, a List<Planet> much more extensible..!